# Order dates chronologically through function

Tags: sql, plsql

So I've created a function that accepts order dates and returns it as the day of the week that the order was placed and to test it I've written a select statement to call on the function. The function works with the select statement however I want the output of days of the week to be listed in chronological order ie. Mon, Tues, Wed...etc. because right now its outputting I believe in the order the orders were place in..all random. How would I rewrite my select statement? I tried using an order by clause but it keeps spitting out the **Not a group by expression error**...Heres my function and select statement so far:

```
create or replace function DAY_ORD_SF
(dtcreated date)
return VARCHAR2

is

begin

    RETURN TO_CHAR(dtcreated,'DAY');
end;
/
```

and this is my select statement:

```
SELECT day_ord_sf(dtcreated), count(*) as "Number of Orders"
  FROM BB_BASKET
  GROUP BY DAY_ORD_SF(DTCREATED)
  ORDER BY TO_CHAR(DTCREATED,'DAY') DESC;
```

can someone help me with the select statement? I've tried placing the order by before and after the group by but its still throwing errors.

Comment: Please EDIT YOUR QUESTION and include the errors you're getting. (And BTW the ORDER BY should follow the GROUP BY, as you have it above). Thanks.

Comment: my errors were listed in the explaining paragraph and the question was posted under the select statement ..i went ahead and bolded it for you thanks!

Comment: Change the ORDER BY to `ORDER BY DAY_ORD_SF(DTCREATED)` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling the function in the `select`, then use that function in the `group by` *and* `order by`:

```
SELECT day_ord_sf(dtcreated), count(*) as "Number of Orders"
FROM BB_BASKET
GROUP BY DAY_ORD_SF(DTCREATED)
ORDER BY TO_CHAR(MIN(DTCREATED), 'DAY') DESC;
```

You could also do this by including the `order by` expression in the `group by` clause:

```
SELECT day_ord_sf(dtcreated), count(*) as "Number of Orders"
FROM BB_BASKET
GROUP BY DAY_ORD_SF(DTCREATED), TO_CHAR(DTCREATED,'DAY')
ORDER BY TO_CHAR(DTCREATED,'DAY') DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a function for this.

Don't sort by a string (e.g. TO_CHAR), it'll only sort alphabetically.

Instead, you can use TRUNC to group all records for a particular day together:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(dtcreated),'DAY'), count(*) as "Number of Orders"
FROM BB_BASKET
GROUP BY TRUNC(dtcreated)
ORDER BY TRUNC(dtcreated) DESC;
```

This will sort by the date in descending order (most recent date first).